# How can I successfully demonstrate using a simple Daffodil method on Red Hat Fuse 7.2 (or 7.3)?

Tags: java-8, redhat, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

***I've been unable to demonstrate using a simple Daffodil method on Red Hat Fuse 7.2 (or 7.3)***

*The camel DSL route call to my "DfdlProcessor.java" process method is shown below...*

```
from ("wmq:queue:DEV.QUEUE.1")
    .process(dfdlProcessor)  <<== failure occurs on this call.
    .log("received message: \"${body}\"");
```

*...causes this exception message...*

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.daffodil.util.LogWriter not found by org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-io
```

*My simple dfdlProcessor's "process()" method looks like...*

```
public void process(org.apache.camel.Exchange exchange) throws IOException, Exception {
    Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();

    System.out.println("**** see if can compile DFDL schema");
    Compiler dfdlCompiler = Daffodil.compiler();  <<== failure occurs here.

    System.out.println("**** done.");        

}
```

**(NOTE: More of the Red Hat Fuse 7.2 console output - i.e., stacktrace - is shown further below)**

*My experience is that Red Hat Fuse is very brittle regarding components/versions and, unfortunately, though I've spent much time/energy - I have not been successful in working thru this issue.*

*Any hint at why I am getting the...*

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/daffodil/util/LogWriter"
```

*...exception would by very appreciated... --A head-scratcher, as it seems I am providing the correct dependency in the pom.xml and also placing that same jar in the "deploy" folder*

*(Also, please note that when the processor call - i.e., ".process(dfdlProcessor)" - is commented out (disabled), the route works perfectly.)*

***red hat fuse 7.2***

***java 8***

***apache daffodil 2.3.0***

---

***EXTRA INFO PROVIDED, BELOW, IF NEEDED***

---

***src/main/java/aaa/bbb/ccc/camel/CamelRoute.java***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.camel;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        CamelContext context = this.getContext(); 
        org.apache.camel.Processor dfdlProcessor = new DfdlProcessor();        

        from ("wmq:queue:DEV.QUEUE.1")
            .process(dfdlProcessor)
            .log("received message: \"${body}\"");            
    }
}
```

***src/main/java/aaa/bbb/ccc/camel/DfdlProcessor.java***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.camel;

import org.apache.camel.Message;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.daffodil.japi.Daffodil;

public class DfdlProcessor implements org.apache.camel.Processor {

    public DfdlProcessor() {
    }

    @Override
    public void process(org.apache.camel.Exchange exchange) throws IOException, Exception {
        Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();

        System.out.println("**** inMessage.toString()=" + inMessage.toString());

        System.out.println("**** see if can compile DFDL schema");
        try {
            org.apache.daffodil.japi.Compiler dfdlCompiler = Daffodil.compiler();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("**** Exception thrown by dfdlCompiler.");
        }

        System.out.println("**** done.");        

    }

    private File getFileFromResources(String fileName) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL resource = classLoader.getResource(fileName);
        if (resource == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("file not found!!!");
        } else {
            return new File(resource.getFile());
        }
    }
}
```

***src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0       
        https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd                            
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint               
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

        <bean class="aaa.bbb.ccc.camel.CamelRoute" id="myRouteBuilder"/>

        <camelContext id="camelBPContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
                <packageScan>
                        <package>aaa.bbb.ccc.camel</package>
                </packageScan>               
        </camelContext>

        <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory" id="wmqcf">
                <property name="hostName" value="localhost"/>
                <property name="port" value="1414"/>
                <property name="queueManager" value="QM1"/>
                <property name="channel" value="DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN"/>
                <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
        </bean>
        <bean
                class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter" id="wmqcfw">
                <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="wmqcf"/>
                <property name="username" value="admin"/>
                <property name="password" value="passw0rd"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration" id="wmqcfg">
                <property name="connectionFactory" ref="wmqcfw"/>
                <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent" id="wmq">
                <property name="configuration" ref="wmqcfg"/>
        </bean>

</blueprint>
```

***src/main/java/META-INF/beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
           bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camelfuseDSL_DFDL_short</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>camelfuseDSL_DFDL_short</name>
    <description>camelfuseDSL_DFDL_short</description>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <version.maven-bundle-plugin>3.2.0</version.maven-bundle-plugin>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <timestamp>v${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd.HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.22.redhat-2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.22.redhat-2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17.redhat-3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>            
        </dependency>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>            
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.daffodil</groupId>
            <artifactId>daffodil-japi_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>                      
        </dependency>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.daffodil</groupId>
            <artifactId>daffodil-io_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>                      
        </dependency>                  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.daffodil</groupId>
            <artifactId>daffodil-lib_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>                     
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.daffodil</groupId>
            <artifactId>daffodil-runtime1_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>                       
        </dependency>                       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.daffodil</groupId>
            <artifactId>daffodil-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>                       
        </dependency>                          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>                      
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>            
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Export-Package>aaa.bbb.ccc*</Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            com.ibm.mq.jms,
                            org.apache.camel.builder;version="[2.21,3)",
                            org.apache.camel.component.jms;version="[2.21,3)",
                            org.apache.camel.model;version="[2.21,3)",
                            org.apache.camel;version="[2.21,3)",
                            org.apache.daffodil.japi*,                                                                                                              
                            org.osgi.service.blueprint;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)",
                            org.springframework.jms.connection,
                            * 
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}-${timestamp}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Require-Capability>
                            osgi.extender; filter:="(osgi.extender=pax.cdi)",
                            org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extension; filter:="(extension=camel-cdi-extension)"
                        </Require-Capability>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***[FUSE_HOME]/deploy***

Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is CC31-A444

Directory of C:\rhf_runtime\fuse-karaf-7.2.0.fuse-720035-redhat-00001\deploy

```
06/05/2019  06:19 PM    <DIR>          .
06/05/2019  06:19 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/03/2019  12:56 PM           792,825 bcpkix-jdk15on.jar
05/03/2019  12:56 PM         4,092,400 bcprov-jdk15on.jar
06/05/2019  06:18 PM            21,733 camelfuseDSL_DFDL_short-1.0.jar
05/03/2019  12:56 PM         8,277,877 com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
05/03/2019  12:56 PM            43,703 com.ibm.mq.traceControl.jar
05/06/2019  01:32 PM           610,259 commons-collections4-4.0.jar
05/03/2019  12:56 PM            22,769 fscontext.jar
05/03/2019  12:56 PM            58,349 jms.jar
02/14/2019  12:17 PM         2,019,728 org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-core-2.3.0.jar
02/14/2019  12:17 PM           365,020 org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-io-2.3.0.jar
02/14/2019  12:17 PM            68,116 org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-japi-2.3.0.jar
02/14/2019  12:17 PM         1,805,190 org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-lib-2.3.0.jar
02/14/2019  12:17 PM         3,163,852 org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-runtime1-2.3.0.jar
05/03/2019  12:56 PM            77,116 providerutil.jar
              14 File(s)     21,418,937 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  546,361,458,688 bytes free
```

***bundles started***

```
karaf@root()> bundle:list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
 ID | State     | Lvl | Version                         | Name
----+-----------+-----+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 28 | Active    |  80 | 7.2.0.fuse-720035-redhat-00001  | Red Hat Fuse :: Fuse Modules :: Transaction
-
-
-
530 | Active    |  90 | 2.0                             | JMS API
533 | Active    |  90 | 4.0.0                           | Apache Commons Collections
536 | Active    |  90 | 0.0.0                           | providerutil.jar
537 | Active    |  90 | 0.0.0                           | com.ibm.mq.traceControl.jar
539 | Active    |  90 | 0.0.0                           | fscontext.jar
541 | Active    |  90 | 1.59                            | bcpkix
542 | Active    |  90 | 0.0.0                           | com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
543 | Active    |  90 | 1.59                            | bcprov
562 | Active    |  90 | 2.3.0                           | org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-japi
579 | Active    |  90 | 2.3.0                           | org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-io
580 | Active    |  90 | 2.3.0                           | org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-core
581 | Active    |  90 | 2.3.0                           | org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-lib
582 | Active    |  90 | 2.3.0                           | org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-runtime1
584 | Active    |  90 | 1.0.0.v20190605221819           | camelfuseDSL_DFDL_short
karaf@root()>
```

***partial console output exception/stacktrace***

```
-
-
-
karaf@root()> log:tail
**** inMessage.toString()=JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:414d5120514d3120202020202020202015cef75c02dec222]
**** see if can compile DFDL schema
18:39:35.448 ERROR [Camel (camelBPContext) thread #5 - JmsConsumer[DEV.QUEUE.1]] Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:414d5120514d3120202020202020202015cef75c02dec222 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-8BL5O58-1559774328863-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-8BL5O58-1559774328863-0-1]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [wmq://queue:DEV.QUEUE.1                                                       ] [         8]
[route1            ] [process1          ] [Processor@0x3d8390da                                                          ] [         5]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-8BL5O58-1559774328863-0-1]
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1846) ~[66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:385) ~[66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:66) ~[66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) [66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:113) [248:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719) [250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679) [250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649) [250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317) [250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255) [250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1168) [250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1160) [250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1057) [250:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.17.RELEASE_1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/daffodil/util/LogWriter
        at org.apache.daffodil.japi.Daffodil.compiler(Daffodil.scala) ~[562:org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-japi:2.3.0]
        at aaa.bbb.ccc.camel.DfdlProcessor.process(DfdlProcessor.java:24) ~[584:aaa.bbb.ccc.camel.camelfuseDSL_DFDL_short:1.0.0.v20190605221819]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) ~[66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.daffodil.util.LogWriter not found by org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-io [579]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1639) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1414) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1660) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1590) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.daffodil.japi.Daffodil.compiler(Daffodil.scala) ~[562:org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-japi:2.3.0]
        at aaa.bbb.ccc.camel.DfdlProcessor.process(DfdlProcessor.java:24) ~[584:aaa.bbb.ccc.camel.camelfuseDSL_DFDL_short:1.0.0.v20190605221819]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) ~[66:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-720050-redhat-00001]
        ... 18 more
-
-
-
```

Comment: `org.apache.daffodil.util.LogWriter not found by org.apache.daffodil.daffodil-io` means one thing. daffodil-io bundle doesn't propely import (if at all) `org.apache.daffodil.util` package, probably from `daffodil-lib` or `daffodil-lib`.

Comment: You have to check at daffodil page/project. Probably they produce wrong OSGi bundles. Fuse 7 doesn't support these libraries officially. It allows to install them (as any OSGi runtime), but Fuse product itself is not supporting these libraries.

Comment: thank you, G!   Guess I'll keep trying.   Please let me know if you have any suggestions for a workaround.   Hopefully where there's a will there's a way.  Ha!

Comment: I don't know if it will help t all, but you certainly should not be deploying the jms.jar as this has the JMS APIs which seem to be provided already in bundle 530.